# Problem with Entra MFA authentication when using a CNAME alias for an Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Database that is configured for MFA authentication using Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory)

It works fine when I connect using:

Server=mydatabase.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive;Initial Catalog=acrisure;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=60;User ID=myuser@mydomain.com@mydatabase

I configured a CNAME alias in another domain:

database.adomain.com -> mydatabase.database.windows.net

The problem is that the configuration string...

Server=database.adomain.com; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive;Initial Catalog=acrisure;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=60;User ID=myuser@mydomain.com@mydatabase

...doesn't work. I get a login failure.

Any ideas?